# MySQL Subquery returns more than 1 row ERROR

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm getting an error on my below mysql query. Please note that my subquery supposed to be returned 1627862 results. Is there any way to sort out this error with maintaining all the conditions of the subquery?

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION_LOG 
SET SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS='D', 
    DEACTIVATION_DATE=NOW(), 
    DEACTIVATION_CHANNEL='SYSTEM' 
WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS ='A' 
AND SHORT_CODE='22222' 
AND MSISDN =(SELECT MSISDN 
             FROM SUBSCRIPTION 
             WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),`ACTIVATION_DATE`) > LAST_CHARGED_VALIDITY 
             AND OFFER_CODE NOT IN ('CAT_228','CAT_229','CAT_232','CAT_233') 
             AND SHORT_CODE = '22222');
```

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: If you want to update all rows that match the values you need `IN`. Equal requires a single value to be returned.

Comment: You could use a JOIN instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal `=` in your MSISDN commpare expects  a single value to be returned by your subquery, but the subquery is returning multiple rows. In order for your query to work, change `=` to `ìn`as below

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION_LOG SET SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS='D', DEACTIVATION_DATE=NOW(), 
DEACTIVATION_CHANNEL='SYSTEM' WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS ='A' 
AND SHORT_CODE='22222' 
AND MSISDN in (SELECT MSISDN 
            FROM SUBSCRIPTION 
         WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),`ACTIVATION_DATE`) > LAST_CHARGED_VALIDITY 
         AND OFFER_CODE NOT IN ('CAT_228','CAT_229','CAT_232','CAT_233') 
         AND SHORT_CODE = '22222');
```

See if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could write this as an update join:

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION_LOG sl
INNER JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s
    ON sl.MSISDN = s.MSIDSN
SET sl.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'D',
    sl.DEACTIVATION_DATE = NOW(),
    sl.DEACTIVATION_CHANNEL = 'SYSTEM'
WHERE
    sl.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'A' AND
    sl.SHORT_CODE = '22222' AND
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), s.ACTIVATION_DATE) > s.LAST_CHARGED_VALIDITY AND
    s.OFFER_CODE NOT IN ('CAT_228','CAT_229','CAT_232','CAT_233') AND
    s.SHORT_CODE = '22222';
```

Comment: After executing the above query, I'm getting this error `Column 'SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS' in field list is ambiguous`.

Comment: @Rezuan Add aliases to everything in the `SET` clause, to refer to the first (target) table.

Comment: Yes, it's fine now. Thank you.